# LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a User entity which represents a User table in my database. This table has a field called `ManagerID` which references another User record (basically an employee to manager mapping). Each User will also have a reference to another table which can have multiple entries, for the sake of this example we will call it `Records`.

So the basic rule is every user can have multiple Records and every user can manage a team of other Users.

So as a small example of what I need to do:

```
User manager = Repository.FindUser('12345');
List<Record> TeamRecordCollection = new List<Record>();

// add the managers records to the team collection
var managerRecords = GetRecords(manager, DateTime.Today);
TeamRecordCollection.AddRange(managerRecords);

// add each individual team members records
foreach (var user in manager.TeamMembers)
{
    var records = GetRecords(user, DateTime.Today);
    TeamRecordCollection.AddRange(records);
}

...

private IEnumerable<Record> GetRecords(User user, DateTime date)
{
    var records = from rec in user.Records
                  where rec.DateSubmitted == date
                  select rec;
    return records.AsEnumerable();
}

// the above code isn't tested it is just a sample idea
```

So what I would like to know is:

a) **Can this be done in the one L2S statement?**

b) **Would it be more efficient than the current way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like;

```
var records = from rec in _DB.Records
              from user in _DB.Users.Where(x => x.ManagerId == managerId ||
                                                x.Id == managerId)
              where rec.UserId == user.Id
              select rec;
```

Comment: I think this looks a good shout, although the Where statement would have to change to user.ManagerID == managerId || user.ID == managerID) as the manager can have records aswell.

Comment: @James: fixed, I think this should work. No idea what the performance implications are though, perhaps do some benchmark tests?

Comment: Had to tweak it a little but all in all this helped me sort it out, thanks. Yeah I will do some benchmarking aswell to test whether it is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Also,

Once you find a LINQ2SQL solution for this one, make sure to use SQL profiler to see the execution plan and tweak as needed.

HTH